# setState doesnt work when using object which has been copied from spread operator

Tags: reactjs, copy, setstate

I have the following codes and it doesn't work and only shows me "undefined" value of orientation object as same as before.

```
let insertDataObj = {...this.state.orientation};
insertDataObj.startTime = "03";
this.setState({
    orientation: insertDataObj,
});
```

however, following codes works like a charm and shows me the "03" value of orientation object as I intended.

```
let insertDataObj = this.state.orientation.
insertDataObj.startTime = "03";
this.setState({
    orientation: insertDataObj,
});
```

So, I am quite confused with the result. I heard that copying object using spread operator should be way more secure and cleaner code than simple copy method and I really thought it would be working as a charm but it doesn't work.
Why is that?

Comment: Could you do `orientation: { ...this.state.orientation, startTime: "03" }`?

Comment: The suggestion you uploaded above also doesn't work.  I don't understand reason why.

Answer (score 1):

Hi It looks like you did not spread the state properly;
When you spread { ...this.state.orientation } you get an object that looks like this.

```
{ startTime: "02" };
rather than
{ orientation: { startTime: "02" } };
You should have done
{ ...this.state };
```

Also it would be a really good idea to use functional setState to reduce code and potential mutation like so.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
   orientation: { ...state.orientation, startTime: "03" },
}));
```